# Why my 'mergesort' fails at large # of numbers?

Tags: c

I have a code of mergesort, it works well with N=68,000 or less, but when the # of numbers increase to 70,000, there's error that some of the elements are not sorted. My friend guess it's because I used too many malloc, but I don't know why.

keytype is just an "unsigned long" type defined by myself. 
A is a pre-set array by
keytype* A = (keytype *)malloc(N * sizeof(keytype));
and filled by random numbers.

```
typedef unsigned long keytype;
keytype *new_part(int start, int end, keytype* A) {
    int N = end - start + 1;
    keytype* cc = (keytype *)malloc(N * sizeof(keytype));
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cc[i] = A[start + i];
    }
    return cc;
}
void mySort(int N, keytype* A){
    if (N == 1) return;
    int mid = N / 2;
    keytype* first = new_part(0, mid - 1, A);
    keytype* second = new_part(mid, N - 1, A);
    mySort(mid, first);
    mySort(N - mid, second);
    int a = 0, b = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (a >= mid) {
            A[i] = second[b];
            b++;
            continue;
        }
        if (b >= N - mid) {
            A[i] = first[a];
            a++;
            continue;
        }
        if (first[a]>second[b]) {
            A[i] = second[b];
            b++;
            continue;
        }
        if (first[a] < second[b]) {
            A[i] = first[a];
            a++;
            continue;
        }
    }
    free(first);
    free(second);
}
```

Comment: What happens in `mysort()` when `N` is zero?

Comment: Have you verified that it's related to array size and not just some specific array characteristics which become more likely as size increases? Consider what happens inside your merge loop when `first[a] == second[b]`.